# Not Able To align Footer at bottom of screen?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I am not able to align the footer at the Bottom of the screen.I have used RelativeLayout within which  **android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"** but the layout is not displayed at the bottom of the screen.

**loan_collection_layout**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/appbar_layout" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:background="#156B7A"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="125dp"
                android:text="Branch Office : Dhankuta"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="13dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="Tuesday -4 April,2017"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="10sp"


                />

        </LinearLayout>


        <!-- Loan collection  -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Loan Collection"
                android:textColor="#2493A7"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="12dp"
                android:layout_height="12dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/filter" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Filter"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="normal" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:background="#98A6A9" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="12dp"
                android:layout_height="12dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.01"
                android:src="@mipmap/search" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="Search"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="normal" />


        </LinearLayout>


        <!-- Linear Layout for 2nd Linear Layout -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <!-- 2nd liner layout ist column  -->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="12dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/center" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Center:005"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.03"
                android:background="#FFFFFF" />


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="12dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/group" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Group"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />


            </LinearLayout>


            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.03"
                android:background="#FFFFFF" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="12dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/loan_type" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Loan Type"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.03"
                android:background="#FFFFFF" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="12dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/date" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Date:"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.03"
                android:background="#FFFFFF" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="12dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/valuedate" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="value date:"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>   <!-- Linear Layout 2nd ends Here -->


        <!-- Linear Layout for Group code starts here-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:buttonTint="#000000" />


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/border_loan_collection">

                <TextView


                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Group Code"
                    android:textColor="#333333"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/border_loan_collection">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Member No."
                    android:textColor="#333333"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/border_loan_collection">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Member Name"
                    android:textColor="#333333"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/border_loan_collection">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Remain Price"
                    android:textColor="#333333"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/border_loan_collection">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Total"
                    android:textColor="#333333"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- 3rd layout starts here -->

        <!-- After third layout you have yo add listView in here and listitem should be populated through the JSON Data -->


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:buttonTint="#333333"
                android:checked="true" />


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#F3F3F3">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="001"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#F3F3F3">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text=" 001"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#F3F3F3">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Bimala Rai"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#F3F3F3">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="0.00"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#F3F3F3">

                <TextView

                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="0.00"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout><!-- 3rd layout ends here-->


        <!-- Linear Layout 4th starts here-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"

            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:buttonTint="#333333" />


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/border_loan_collection">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="001"
                    android:textColor="#333333"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/border_loan_collection">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="001"
                    android:textColor="#333333"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/border_loan_collection">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Uranus"
                    android:textColor="#333333"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/border_loan_collection">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="0.00"
                    android:textColor="#333333"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/border_loan_collection">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="0.00"
                    android:textColor="#333333"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>  <!-- 4th linear layout ends here -->




        <!-- Total Bottom Layout starts herel -->

        <!-- Footer aligned to bottom -->

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="Footer"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp" />



    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

> How can footer be displayed at bottom of screen??

Comment: Use `android:gravity="bottom"` and `android:layout_gravity="bottom"` for `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: not working @piyush

Comment: put your text view (footer view) just before closing tag of parent relative layout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You main view is LinearLayout which does not works the way you are trying it to.

For obtaining your desired result you need your main Layout to be Relative layout and then set align bottom true to your footer.

For eg:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- place all your view inside this layout-->

    </LinearLayout>

       <!--place your footer here with align bottom property set to true-->

         <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="Footer"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
</RelativeLayout/>
```

This snippet should get you going.

Comment: put your text view (footer view) just before closing tag of parent relative layout

Comment: Actually the linear layout inside the parent relative layout is useless in your case. You could have achieved it by RelativeLayout attributes such as `android:layout_below="@+id/view_id"`

Comment: @AldrinMathew yes he could have done that. But i gave him the most feasible solution to work less with

Answer (score 1):

You have two options, either follow @Anirudh Sharma's answer, or just make your `RelativeLayout`'s height to `match_parent`.

Answer (score 1):

Your parent linear layout will stack your views in the orientation you have provided in your layout in order, one after the other. `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` would work only for views defined **inside a RelativeLayout** and not in the way you have defined.

Make your parent layout as RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout and it would work perfectly for you!

Answer (score 1):

Add following just above your footer

```
<View
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp" />
```

Comment: @Ghimire, I am not sure whether this is the best solution, but I have used this trick in several occasions and it has worked for me well.

Comment: its also working on me.but it is alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is AlignParentBottom only works when the view is inside a Relative Layout. Your Textview is inside a Linear Layout.Put it outside of the Linear Layout and Inside the parent Relative Layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/appbar_layout" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:background="#156B7A"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

       .
       .
       .
       .
  </LinearLayout> 

    <!-- Make sure your View is directly the child of Relative layout to use 
    alignParentBottom="true" -->



    <!-- Footer aligned to bottom  -->

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Footer"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rl"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/footer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="#6AED83"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:text="Footer"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, it will work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1">
//Your other code will be here
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="Footer"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Whatever you want in footer make sure you write code inside main parent layout(Relative layout) so u sill set android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
and it will remain all the time

.Note that write that code just above the </RelativeLayout> (Closing of main parent layout ). So footer never get hidden by any other layout.
```