# The menu item is overlapping by footer when scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I have Activity with the header, the menu and the footer. 
If I change the **orientation** of the screen to horizontal so that the scroll appears, then the **footer will overlap the last menu item (button6)**. If I click on the footer, then the handler of the Button6 is triggered.

How to make that the **footer not overlap the menu item** and I can see all menu items?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.test.test.MainMenuActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:background="@color/colorMainWhite"
    style="@style/root_layout">

    <!--- Header-->
    <include layout="@layout/content_header"/>
    <include layout="@layout/content_subheader"/>

    <!--- Menu-->
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/myview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/InfoLayout"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/size_15px"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        style="@style/los_lo_info_item">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvNL1"
            tools:text="test"
            style="@style/tvs_lo_text_32_bold_ellipsized"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvNL2"
            tools:text="test"
            style="@style/tvs_lo_text_26_ellipsized"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            style="@style/los_lo_mainmenu_item">
            <ImageView
                style="@style/icon_default_size_center"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_1"/>
            <TextView
                style="@style/tvs_lo_text_mainmenu_button"
                android:text="@string/title_item_1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            style="@style/los_lo_mainmenu_item">
            <ImageView
                style="@style/icon_default_size_center"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_2"/>
            <TextView
                style="@style/tvs_lo_text_mainmenu_button"
                android:text="@string/title_item_2"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            style="@style/los_lo_mainmenu_item">
            <ImageView
                style="@style/icon_default_size_center"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_3"/>
            <TextView
                style="@style/tvs_lo_text_mainmenu_button"
                android:text="@string/title_item_3"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            style="@style/los_lo_mainmenu_item">
            <ImageView
                style="@style/icon_default_size_center"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_4"/>
            <TextView
                style="@style/tvs_lo_text_mainmenu_button"
                android:text="@string/title_item_4"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            style="@style/los_lo_mainmenu_item">
            <ImageView
                style="@style/icon_default_size_center"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_5"/>
            <TextView
                style="@style/tvs_lo_text_mainmenu_button"
                android:text="@string/title_item_5"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            style="@style/los_lo_mainmenu_item">
            <ImageView
                style="@style/icon_default_size_center"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_6"/>
            <TextView
                style="@style/tvs_lo_text_mainmenu_button"
                android:text="@string/title_item_6"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
<!--- Footer-->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="bottom">
    <LinearLayout
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/size_20px"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/size_20px"
        android:background="@color/colorBgLightGrey"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/icon_logos_ips"
            style="@style/ips_icons_style"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

new:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.test.test.MainMenuActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/layout_content_header"
        layout="@layout/content_header"/>
    <include
        android:id="@+id/layout_content_subheader"
        android:layout_below="@id/layout_content_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/content_subheader"/>

    <!--- Menu-->
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/myview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/layout_content_subheader"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/merchantInfoLayout"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/size_15px"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                style="@style/los_lo_merchant_info_item">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvNL1"
                    tools:text="test"
                    style="@style/tvs_lo_text_32_bold_ellipsized"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvNL2"
                    tools:text="test"
                    style="@style/tvs_lo_text_26_ellipsized"/>
            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    style="@style/los_lo_mainmenu_item">
                    <ImageView
                        style="@style/icon_default_size_center"
                        android:src="@drawable/icon_1"/>
                    <TextView
                        style="@style/tvs_lo_text_mainmenu_button"
                        android:text="@string/title_item_1"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    style="@style/los_lo_mainmenu_item">
                    <ImageView
                        style="@style/icon_default_size_center"
                        android:src="@drawable/icon_2"/>
                    <TextView
                        style="@style/tvs_lo_text_mainmenu_button"
                        android:text="@string/title_item_2"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    style="@style/los_lo_mainmenu_item">
                    <ImageView
                        style="@style/icon_default_size_center"
                        android:src="@drawable/icon_3"/>
                    <TextView
                        style="@style/tvs_lo_text_mainmenu_button"
                        android:text="@string/title_item_3"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/button4"
                    style="@style/los_lo_mainmenu_item">
                    <ImageView
                        style="@style/icon_default_size_center"
                        android:src="@drawable/icon_4"/>
                    <TextView
                        style="@style/tvs_lo_text_mainmenu_button"
                        android:text="@string/title_item_4"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/button5"
                    style="@style/los_lo_mainmenu_item">
                    <ImageView
                        style="@style/icon_default_size_center"
                        android:src="@drawable/icon_5"/>
                    <TextView
                        style="@style/tvs_lo_text_mainmenu_button"
                        android:text="@string/title_item_5"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/button6"
                    style="@style/los_lo_mainmenu_item">
                    <ImageView
                        style="@style/icon_default_size_center"
                        android:src="@drawable/icon_6"/>
                    <TextView
                        style="@style/tvs_lo_text_mainmenu_button"
                        android:text="@string/title_item_6"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="bottom">
        <LinearLayout
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/size_20px"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/size_20px"
            android:background="@color/colorBgLightGrey"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/icon_logos_ips"
                style="@style/ips_icons_style"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding these to `ScrollView` will work

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Using [android:layout_weight](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html) and as LinearLayout has `android:orientation="vertical"`, keep footer below `ScrollView`

check layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!--- Header-->
        <include layout="@layout/content_header" />

        <!--- Menu-->
        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/myview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/InfoLayout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingTop="15dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvNL1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        tools:text="test" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvNL2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        tools:text="test" />
                </LinearLayout>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/button1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_hardware_keyboard_arrow_left" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="title_item_1" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/button2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_hardware_keyboard_arrow_left" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="title_item_2" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/button3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_hardware_keyboard_arrow_left" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="title_item_3" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/button4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_hardware_keyboard_arrow_left" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="title_item_4" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/button5"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_hardware_keyboard_arrow_left" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="title_item_5" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/button6"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_hardware_keyboard_arrow_left" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="title_item_6" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/button7"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_hardware_keyboard_arrow_left" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="title_item_7" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/button8"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_hardware_keyboard_arrow_left" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="title_item_8" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <!--- Footer-->
        <include layout="@layout/content_subheader" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is your `content_subheader.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="20px"
        android:paddingTop="20px">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_hardware_keyboard_arrow_left" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Note** : i have removed all your styles from layout as i dont have its attributes

---

new :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!--- Header-->
        <include
            android:id="@+id/header"
            layout="@layout/header_layout" />

        <!--- Menu-->
        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/myview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/header"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/InfoLayout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingTop="15dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvNL1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        tools:text="test" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvNL2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        tools:text="test" />
                </LinearLayout>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/button1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_hardware_keyboard_arrow_left" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="title_item_1" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/button2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_hardware_keyboard_arrow_left" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="title_item_2" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/button3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_hardware_keyboard_arrow_left" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="title_item_3" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/button4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_hardware_keyboard_arrow_left" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="title_item_4" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/button5"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_hardware_keyboard_arrow_left" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="title_item_5" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/button6"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_hardware_keyboard_arrow_left" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="title_item_6" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/button7"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_hardware_keyboard_arrow_left" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="title_item_7" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/button8"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_hardware_keyboard_arrow_left" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="title_item_8" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <!--- Footer-->
        <include layout="@layout/footer_layout" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: For horizontal orientation my problem solved. Thank you! But in vertical orientation the Footer should be at the bottom of the screen, but it stuck to the ScrollView. Between the ScrollView and the Footer  must be an empty area in vertical orientstion. How can I do this?

Comment: I did it. Please help with the problem with issue of vertical orientation.

Comment: Please try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43672004/not-able-to-align-footer-at-bottom-of-screen and inform me if you stuck anywhere

Comment: I changed the CoordinatorLayout by the RelativeLayout and added to the Footer android:layout_alignParentBottom="true". But nothing has changed. Please see code: https://codeshare.io/5M9Jpn

Comment: no. dont change CoordinatorLayout  keept it as it is just change first linearlayout to RelativeLayout

Comment: Now all that is inside the ScrollView is invisible. Please see code: https://codeshare.io/5XKP9j

Comment: that is blocked page in my office i cant open that

Comment: Ok, thank you. If you need I can place my code where you wish.

Comment: replace below in your code and check

**<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!--- Header-->
        <include
            android:id="@+id/header"
            layout="@layout/header_layout" />//add this

        <!--- Menu-->
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_below="@+id/header"> //add this**

Comment: and yes, can you do one thing for me ?

Comment: I did it. But nothing has changed. Where can I put my code to look at?  What can I do?

Comment: If I replace  android:layout_height="0dp" to  android:layout_height="match_parent", than I have my first problem in horizontal orientation. take code below new in my updated answer

Comment: wait there is some confusion post it as a new question

Comment: I created a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46340642/how-to-anchor-the-footer-at-the-bottom-of-the-screen-in-vertical-orientation